# Search from comma separated values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have user tables which contains column `city_id` and inside this column city ids are stored as comma separated values as following:

**User**

```
user_id  user_name     city_id    
1        ahmar_arshad   1,2,3
2        abdul_muiz     15,2,9
3        abdul_momin    1,2,13
```

Now I want to search rows which contains city `id = 1` from `city_id` column.

How it can be done?

Comment: `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: I need in PostgreSQL  .

Comment: consider 3NF.....

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general solution, which should work on Postgres:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ',' || city_id || ',' LIKE '%,1,%';
```

[image]

### Demo

The trick here is to compare the CSV list of city IDs in the form, e.g. `,1,2,3,` against `,ID,`, where `ID` can be any individual city ID.

Note that it would be best to normalize your table and store those city IDs across separate records instead of in CSV strings.  This would make querying your data easier, and would probably also increase performance.

Answer (score 5):

If you convert that comma separated list to an array you can use Postgres' powerful array operators:

```
select *
from cities
where '1' = any (string_to_array(city_id, ','));
```

If you need to find rows with on of several ID's

```
select *
from cities
where string_to_array(city_id, ',') && array['1', '2']
```

The `&&` is the "overlaps" operator for arrays. If you need to find rows that contain all of a list of IDs: you can use the contains operator:

```
select *
from cities
where string_to_array(city_id, ',') @> array['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 3):

Check This.

you should use `string_to_array` to spilt column and then use city_id='1' conditon in where clause.

```
select * from (
select id,user_name,unnest(string_to_array(city_id, ',')) city_id
from RT
)a where city_id='1'
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/AHV20256) Here.

> OutPut

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
SELECT      *
FROM        [Table Name]
WHERE       city_id  LIKE '1,%,%' 
OR          city_id  LIKE '%,1,%'
OR          city_id  LIKE '%,%,1';
```

Comment: it would fail if the column contains just one value, so with no comma, or just 2 values, or 4 and more

Answer (score 0):

Try this One..

--**********************************************************************************

--Creating Table structure for the reference

create table #test (user_id int,user_name varchar(100),city_id varchar(25))

insert into #test values (1,'ahmar_arshad','1,2,3')
insert into #test values (1,'abdul_muiz','15,2,9')
insert into #test values (1,'abdul_momin','1,2,13')

--select * from #test

--**********************************************************************************

-- Query

select user_id,user_name,city_id from 
(
select user_id,user_name,city_id,replace(city_id,',','*') as City_ID2
from #test
)A
where City_ID2 like '%1*%'

-- Replace comma with star(*) and then search.

--**********************************************************************************

Comment: updating query..

select user_id,user_name,city_id from 
(
select user_id,user_name,city_id,replace(city_id,',','*') as City_ID2
from #test
)A
where City_ID2 like '%1*%'

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE  user_id LIKE '%1%';
```

you can search like keyword  on w3school

Comment: This would match the ID `13`, since `%` matches `1` followed by anything (not my down vote).